# Why is it legal to set a property you can't get?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I would like to understand why it is allowed to assign a property on a string or other primitive, even though javascript never stores that value.I know that "xyz" is not the same as Object("xyz"), but look at here

```
var o = "xyz";
o.value = "foo bar";
alert(o.value); // alerts "undefined"
```

The value property stays undefined right after being assigned.
When o is an object, the value property is assigned properly and returned in the alert statement.
When o is undefined, assigning the property results in a TypeError.
But when o is a string, nothing happens at all, the assignment is simply ignored.
Ok, in my example o is a variable, but also "xyz".value = "foo bar" is perfectly legal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are not objects. This:

```
 o.value = "foo bar";
```

means:

1. Convert the string value of "o" to a String instance
2. Set the property "value" of that instance to "foo bar"
3. Throw the String object away.

Comment: is there any *rationale* behind this?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath well, in JavaScript the type "string" is not the same as the type "String".  I don't know what the rationale is; String instances (like Number instances) are immutable, so it's not clear why they ended up being distinct. Since JavaScript was designed in such a hurry, it's probably pointless to look for deep meaning :)

Comment: That's what I thought. It's just that it's easier (for me) to remember something if it makes sense ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ha ha definitely. There's probably some performance argument to be made; letting the runtime complete "own" the nature of a string constant probably makes some optimizations easier.

Comment: actually I was asking about the auto conversion to String... or more precisely, in this particular example. because it looks completely pointless.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ah, well because lower-case "s" strings are **not** objects, if it didn't auto-box the string in a String then the expression would have to be an error. The `.` and `[ ]` operators are defined such that the left-hand side is *always* coerced to an Object type.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath right. Since the coercion is basically invisible, the spec says that an implementation is free to avoid doing it if there's a short-cut. However, it'd still be true in this case that after the assignment, there's no object hanging around and so there's nowhere to find that property. I suspect a modern JavaScript runtime might simply ignore that statement altogether!